# How to format dateTime in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, datetime-format

That:

```
{{ wpis.entry.lastChangeDate|date:"D d M Y" }}
```

gives me (why?):

```
2009-07-24 21:45:38.986156
```

And, I don't know how to skip fraction part...

In my model, I have:

```py
addedDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Comment: Of course there is, here is all line <li>{{ wpis.entry.UserID.username }} @ [{{ wpis.entry.lastChangeDate|date:"D d M Y" }}]</li>

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Are you sure your lastChangeDate is Django DateTime?

Comment: It is for addedDate not for lastChangeDate, that's why I am wondering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this:

`addedDate = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)`

Answer (score 233):

This is exactly what you want. Try this:

```
{{ wpis.entry.lastChangeDate|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}
```

Comment: Details on all available formatting options are Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Answer (score 5):

I suspect `wpis.entry.lastChangeDate` has been somehow transformed into a string in the view, before arriving to the template.

In order to verify this hypothesis, you may just check in the view if it has some property/method that only strings have - like for instance `wpis.entry.lastChangeDate.upper`, and then see if the template crashes.

You could also create your own [custom filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), and use it for debugging purposes, letting it inspect the object, and writing the results of the inspection on the page, or simply on the console. It would be able to inspect the object, and check if it is really a DateTimeField.

On an unrelated notice, why don't you use `models.DateTimeField(`[**`auto_now_add`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)`=True)` to set the datetime on creation?

Answer (score 3):

`{{ wpis.entry.lastChangeDate|date:"SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" }}`
Replace **SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT** with the date and/or time format you desire to use.

Here's a list of available date and time formats to use in Django templates :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#time

Make sure the filter is applied to the correct field.

Comment: This also properly supports languages and localizations.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, [time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#time) filter below can only show a formatted time:

```
{{ wpis.entry.lastChangeDate|time:'H:i' }}
```