# I am getting timestamp as 2017-12-16 06:32:34.715731+00:00, I want it in the format of 2017-12-16 06:32:34

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

```
class Registration(models.Model):

    requester_first_name = models.CharField("First name", max_length=50)
    requester_last_name = models.CharField("Last name", max_length=50)
    requester_email = models.CharField("Email", max_length=50)
    requester_phone = models.CharField("Mobile", max_length=20)
    requester_title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=50)

    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

this is my model I have imported "`from django.utils import timezone`" and also in settings I have mentioned `DATETIME_FORMAT = 'j N Y, P'`

Comment: [Don't add ASAP to your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: https://pymotw.com/3/datetime/#formatting-and-parsing

Comment: You can try with that: `timezone.now().replace(microsecond=0)` in the model instead `timezone.now`. They explain in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1512640/3540693)