# Date type field value format in Django template

Tags: django, django-forms

I have custom form in template file.

```
<form> <input type="date" value={{info.from_date|date:'Y-m-d'}}> </form>
```

Here `info.from_date` is `context data`.

In this case in FORM on page, date is always showing in format `'dd-mm-yyyy'`.
But I want in `'mm-dd-yyyy'`. So how to change this format.

Problem is not in the whole template. problem is in the value of a date field.So i have mentioned the code also. I want to know how to format my template like this:

```
value={{info.from_date|date:'Y-m-d'}} in input type=date
```

Please any body share any idea !

Comment: No, completely different. In my case its specific to the date field itself in the form. Apart from the date field value in form this is fine in remaining part of template. I want to format the date value in date field in the form only.

Comment: @Caleb Goodman . This question is not duplicate. I am talking about the format of date value in date field in a form, not any where in the template.

Comment: This answer is wrong !  Its not duplicate. @Caleb Goodman  you should read my answer. It will clear your concept !

Comment: relax, I agree.  Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180372/how-to-format-datetime-in-django-template) that might be what others are looking for, but isn't a duplicate.

Comment: You are using a django form for this right?  I think I have a solution.

Answer (score 3):

m   Month, 2 digits with leading zeros. '01' to '12'
n   Month without leading zeros.    '1' to '12'

d   Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros.  '01' to '31'
j   Day of the month without leading zeros. '1' to '31'

y   Year, 2 digits. '99'
Y   Year, 4 digits. '1999'

so {{value|date:'m-d-Y'}}

Comment: from view i am passing the date object  in format  2019-09-13 as context data.  In my template file(.html file) , i have written  code like this --               
 <input type="date" id="from_date" name="from_date" value = {% if from_date %}  {{from_date|date:date_format}} {% else %} {{cal_min_date}} {% endif %} min={{cal_min_date}} max={{cal_max_date}}>                 Here date_format is "Y-m-d" . In this way its working fine but if i am changing any other format , value in date field is not displayed. In date field following is displayed - 'mm-dd-yyyy'

Comment: IS there any issue in settings.py file ?

Answer (score 0):

I found interesting answer of this issue.
This is not the Django issue. And there is no solution in Django to use different format in this case. Here there is limitation of HTML field of type="date".
type="date" field in HTML only supports ISO 8601 dates format. And in field date field is automatically picked the locale format. So its not in our hand to use any format in any machine's browser. 
So correct answer is that we can not handle here date format in Django.

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/nov/08/html5-input-typedate-formatting-issues#Problem-#1:-Browser-Support