# Converting Date to "1434758400000" with pd.datetime in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, time-series

I'm working on a Django project, and I've encountered an issue when using the pd.datetime function. When I try to convert a date using pd.datetime, it's returning a value like "1434758400000" instead of a proper datetime object. I'm puzzled by this behavior and unsure of what could be causing it.

Dates looks like this and they are of object dtypes

```
date        
2015-06-20 
2015-06-20     
2015-06-20  
2015-06-20 
2015-06-20
```

After `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`, the dates changed to:

```
dates
1434758400000
1434758400000
1434758400000
1434758400000
1434758400000
```

Here's a code snippet that illustrates the problem:

```
# Convert the 'date' column to a datetime object
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Create a DataFrame to represent all unique date-district combinations
unique_dates = pd.date_range(start=df['date'].min(), end=df['date'].max())
unique_districts = df['pdistrict'].unique()

date_district_combinations = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([unique_dates, unique_districts], names=['date', 'pdistrict'])
full_df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_district_combinations).reset_index()

# Merge this new DataFrame with original data to fill in missing combinations
filled_df = full_df.merge(df, on=['date', 'pdistrict'], how='left')

# Fill missing 'cases' with 0 
filled_df['cases'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

*The output of this code is something like: "1434758400000".*

I would expect the output to be a valid datetime object, but this unexpected behavior is causing issues in my project. Has anyone encountered this before or can provide insights into what might be going wrong?

I've checked my code and the input date format, and they seem correct. Could there be any configuration settings in Django or Pandas that could cause this issue?

Edit:

I have tried `pred_df[selected_date_feature] = pd.to_datetime(pred_df[selected_date_feature], unit='ms')` *An error occurred: non convertible value 2015-06-20 with the unit 'ms', at position 0*

Comment: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='ms')`

Comment: I have tried that but got this error `An error occurred: non convertible value 2015-06-20 with the unit 'ms', at position 0`

Comment: OK, so final DataFrame change datetimes to unix times? `print (filled_df.head())` ?

Comment: The problem is here `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` It is throwing error there.  How can the `(filled_df.head())`.

Comment: So there are datetimes like `2015-06-20` and `1434758400000` in column `date`, so failed `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` and also `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='ms')` ?

Comment: Like `df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1434758400000','2015-06-20']})`

Comment: I have edit the question and added the sample dates data. you can look there

Comment: OK, and after `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` dates was changed to `1434758400000` ? If use  `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` and then `print (df.head())` ?

Comment: Yes exactly. After `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`, the dates change to `1434758400000 `

Comment: Everything works fine in google colab and jupyter but when I'm using it in django it is showing this behavior

Comment: Can you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180372/how-to-format-datetime-in-django-template

Comment: I am not using models in django. I am just printing in terminal